# Meteor 0.9.0 Breaks My Mongo Database?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I recently updated Meteor and am experiencing several annoying bugs that makes it hard to work on my project.  For example, when I run

```
meteor
```

It gives me this:

```
=> Started proxy.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
 This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database.
Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does
not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.
```

I am running this as root on debian, so it shouldn't be a permissions error...  But I am new to Linux so maybe that's what it is....

I run:

```
meteor reset
```

and it will run my program but as soon as I run

```
meteor mongo
```

to access my database, but then I get this:

```
=> Exited from signal : SIGKILL
Killed
```

And it breaks my project and I get the unexpected mongo exit code 100 again.

This was not happening until Meteor 0.9.0  is this a bug, or a Linux permission error?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked permissions on '.meteor/local`? Is your Debian environment running inside a VM (eg. VirtualBox or VMware)?

Comment: Did you start meteor with `sudo` before and are not using it now? Change the permissions on that folder so that you don't have to use sudo.

Comment: I'm in root so I don't need to sudo my commands, and yes its in a VM (Oracle VirtualBox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem in Codio.io. 
Your VM maybe running out of disk space. 
Free VMs have limited space, cod.io gives you 1gb.
Meteor has grown in size with the 0.9.0 and 0.9.1 update(i think it is ~300mb), that combined with mongoDB needing 450mb doesn't leave a lot of room. 
to see how much space you project is taking up use:

```
du -h
```

that will list you project size and add the 450mb for monogdb and see if it more than the space allotted for you VM.

specific to cod.io you can run:

```
df -h | grep xvdc | head -1 | awk '{print "free: " $4 " of " $2 ". Used: " $3}'
```

to see how much space you have left

to fix my problem I moved my mongoDB to mongoHQ(compose.io) and set up a an AWS sandbox DB(free!!!!!)

then when you start up meteor you point to it with:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:pass@xxxx.mongohq.com:xxxxx/xxxx meteor
```

Comment: But my VM isn't free, its on my own computer, so is space still the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issues trying to start a meteor app and exactly the mongodb server is being terminated in an unexpectly manner. Generally a virtual linux like the one you mentioned is coming without a **swap** partition (check in **/etc/fstab** file) so if you have not enough memory to allocate MongoDB server then meteor app can't be started. You can create a [swap partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2208/79050) or upgrade the memory available for your virtual machine. Also you can emulate a swap partition through [swapspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134258/dynamically-growing-swap-file-on-debian/134261)

```
sudo apt-get install swapspace
```

After that I'm able to start the meteor app... Just be patient as swap memory is not as faster as RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the mongodb.lock file found in .meteor/local/db folder

Comment: do I just delete it?  Will it change my code or Mongo.db at all?

Comment: Deleted it and I'm still getting the same problem...  Why do I keep getting SIGKILL ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Meteorite? Maybe the problem is with some package.

> When you [update to 0.9.0](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/08/26/meteor-090-new-packaging-system), if you've been using Meteorite, you will be
>   prompted to upgrade your project using **`mrt migrate-app`**. And
>   atmospherejs.com has been updated to point at the official package
>   server – check it out!